# How do I get the position of a DOM element (also nested) in relation to body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, position

I have the body element and HTML in it.
How do I get the inner3 element left position in relation to `body`?

```
<body>
   <div>
       <h2 id='inner3'>some text</h2>
   </div>
</body>
```

Obviously, in Java-script, preferably in jQuery

Comment: Have I missed something, or will `$('#inner3').offset().left` suffice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

html:

```
<body>
   <div>
       <h2 id='inner3'>some text</h2>
       <span id='result'>tmp</span>
   </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
h2 {
    margin-left: 300px
}
```

javascript:

> $('#result').html($('#inner3').offset().left)
>
> $('#inner3').offset().left // this return the left position!

link: http://jsfiddle.net/A5kQy/

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You can get the position of your `inner3` element using jQuery's `.position()` or `.offset()` method.

> **jQuery.position()** Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.
>
> **jQuery.offset()** Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document

#### Sample

```
$("#inner3").position().left
```

or

```
$("#inner3").offset().left
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.position()](http://Get%20the%20current%20coordinates%20of%20the%20first%20element%20in%20the%20set%20of%20matched%20elements,%20relative%20to%20the%20offset%20parent.)
- [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)